# linux (ubuntu) graphical login from a remote computer before session is logged in

Tags: login, remote, gui, vnc

I have the ability to VNC into a remotely hosted ubuntu session with VNC *after* I've logged into that desktop session locally on that machine. My problem comes when I want to restart the computer (lands on the graphical prompt).

More importantly to me if this graphical server is logged in I can ssh in and direct my display to :0 and run a vmplayer process in that session and RDP to it.

```
export DISPLAY=:0; 
nohup vmrun -T player start /vms/winsvr2012/winsvr2012.vmx gui &
```

Unfortunately this can only be done *after* I've actually got a graphical session running at the other end. (Basically I need to be there in person to start the computer and start the session).

What I want to do is run wakeonlan remotely and get into a remote graphical session, so I can start persistent graphical programs. I've had no success with:
startx
xpra

Comment: I've simply had to make ubuntu boot straight into a graphical session, unfortunately now I it seems I cannot automatically lock the screen - so I simply need to wait for the lock to turn on after 1minute. But it does the job at least. (I've googled a bit)